# View CPU and memory usage in mode line

Tags: mode-line

How can I configure Emacs so that it displays CPU and memory usage in the mode line?

The package [mode-line-stats](https://github.com/Idorobots/mode-line-stats) does this, but it has not been developed for several years, and it has not been submitted to any online package repository.

Comment: What's wrong with `mode-line-stats`?  I just tried it in Emacs 26.1 and it appears to work as advertised.  No recent development can just mean that it's already feature-complete, and nothing is broken.

Comment: Weird, it doesn't work for me on 26.1. I just get `Error running timer ‘mls-memory-update’: (wrong-type-argument number-or-marker-p nil`. Maybe I'm installing it incorrectly. My mode line just says `c?dl` with nothing else.

Comment: Not sure about the error.  `M-x mls-mode-line-toggle` to switch between that (very) compact display, and the expanded information?

Comment: The error comes because it call "free -o" to get memory information, but "-o" is not support by free command now.